# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I add in Db Unique Key Constraint

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.sysconstraints WHERE constid = OBJECT_ID('UX_AccountDataTransaction_TransactionId')) BEGIN     ALTER TABLE dbo.AccountDataTransactions     ADD CONSTRAINT UX_AccountDataTransaction_TransactionId UNIQUE CLUSTERED (TransactionId) END GO
```

And When I get data from some services I want to save it into table but always have error

```
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UX_AccountDataTransaction_TransactionId'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AccountDataTransactions'. The duplicate key value is (87000058395348).
```

I check before I save and there are no duplicate keys.

My code

```
List<Wallet.Api.Repository.Db.Models.AccountDataTransaction> result = await SaveTransactionsAsync(accparams, cancellationToken);
```

```
_context.AttachRange(result);
```

```
_ = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Code for model

```
public partial class AccountDataTransaction
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string? AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string? TransactionId { get; set; }
    public string? InstructionId { get; set; }
    public string? Source { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string? Direction { get; set; }
    public string? Status { get; set; }
    public decimal AmountLocal { get; set; }
    public string? Currency { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? ValueDate { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? TransactionTime { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public string? TransactionKind { get; set; }
    public string? CreditorName { get; set; }
    public string? CreditorAddressLine { get; set; }
    public string? CreditorLocality { get; set; }
    public string? CreditorCountry { get; set; }
    public string? CreditorAccount { get; set; }
    public string? CreditorBank { get; set; }
    public string? DebtorName { get; set; }
    public string? DebtorAddressLine { get; set; }
    public string? DebtorLocality { get; set; }
    public string? DebtorCountry { get; set; }
    public string? DebtorAccount { get; set; }
    public string? DebtorBank { get; set; }
    public string? Purpose { get; set; }
    public string? PurposeCode { get; set; }
    public string? CreditorReference { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? DateTo { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
}
```

If you need more code or ask for additional explanation.

Thank you

I try to save list of objects into DB with EF 7 into table with Unique Key Constraint

Comment: Either the ID already exists or your data contains duplicates. SQL Server does not lie.

Comment: @Charlieface you were right SQL doesn't lie I had a bug in the code when checking for duplicates now it's fixed and it works as it should thanks everyone. You can give me negative points now :D